# What is the difference between IOT and a normal index?

Tags: oracle, indexing

Please help me in getting the diff between IOT and a normal index

Answer (score 2):

An IOT is a **table** stored in a variation of a B-tree index structure. In a heap-organized table, rows are inserted where they fit. In an index-organized table, rows are stored in an index defined on the primary key for the table. Each index entry in the B-tree also stores the non-key column values. Thus, the index is the data, and the data is the index. Applications manipulate index-organized tables just like heap-organized tables, using SQL statements.

For an analogy of an index-organized table, suppose a human resources manager has a book case of cardboard boxes. Each box is labeled with a number—1, 2, 3, 4, and so on—but the boxes do not sit on the shelves in sequential order. Instead, each box contains a pointer to the shelf location of the next box in the sequence.

Folders containing employee records are stored in each box. The folders are sorted by employee ID. Employee King has ID 100, which is the lowest ID, so his folder is at the bottom of box 1. The folder for employee 101 is on top of 100, 102 is on top of 101, and so on until box 1 is full. The next folder in the sequence is at the bottom of box 2.

In this analogy, ordering folders by employee ID makes it possible to search efficiently for folders without having to maintain a separate index. Suppose a user requests the records for employees 107, 120, and 122. Instead of searching an index in one step and retrieving the folders in a separate step, the manager can search the folders in sequential order and retrieve each folder as found.

Index-organized tables provide faster access to table rows by primary key or a valid prefix of the key. The presence of non-key columns of a row in the leaf block avoids an additional data block I/O. For example, the salary of employee 100 is stored in the index row itself. Also, because rows are stored in primary key order, range access by the primary key or prefix involves minimal block I/Os. Another benefit is the avoidance of the space overhead of a separate primary key index.

For more, read [Overview of IOT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/indexiot.htm#CNCPT911)

Answer (score 1):

An IOT is not an index into a table, it *is* the table.

It has the same structure as a (B-tree) index, but instead of containing a rowid that points into the table, it contains the whole row.

This has the side-effect that there are no permanent rowids for the records in that table (because they get moved around as the index is re-organized). This is a bit of a problem if you want to build additional indexes on the IOT. It is solved by using extended rowids: The secondary index contains a rowid, but in case it is not valid anymore, it also contains the primary key so that you can still identify the row.